# jQuery move a sibblings element before the selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, siblings

I have this html:

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input class="form-control radio-matrix">
  <p>Text</p>
</label>
```

*I have to use jQuery** to do this, and I also have to do it by selecting the class .radio-matrix, any ideas?

I've tried several methods after the selector:

```js
$('input.radio-matrix').siblings("p")
```

Comment: What is it you want to do, after selecting the `<p>`?

Comment: You haven't explained what expected results are

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to switch positions loop through them and do something like:

```js
$('.radio-matrix').each(function(){
   // "this" is instance of the radio-matrix class
   $(this).next().insertBefore(this);
   // or
   $(this).siblings('p').insertBefore(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input class="form-control radio-matrix">
  <p>Text</p>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) your method is great because I have several labels, and that way it applys to each one!

Comment: right...will have problems without looping and dealing with specific instances when more than one such group exists

Answer (score 0):

Use `before` like the following:

```js
$('input.radio-matrix').before($('p'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input class="form-control radio-matrix">
  <p>Text</p>
</label>
```

Comment: won't work if more than one of these, or if `<p>` exists elsewhere in page

Answer (score 0):

This inverts the selected element (`$selectedElement`) and the element following it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $selectedElement = $(".radio-matrix");
    var $selectedElementSibling = $(".radio-matrix").next();

    $selectedElementSibling.after($selectedElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input class="form-control radio-matrix">
    <p>Text</p>
</label>
```